Dimension of algebra after an extension of scalars
Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and $L/K$ be a field extension. Denote $A_L=A\otimes_K L$.
When does $$\dim_K(A)=\dim_L(A_L)$$ hold?
I thought it is always true, but how we can explain the following:
Let $A \cong Mat_n(\mathbb{C})$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. Then $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(A)=2n^2$. However,$$A_{\mathbb{C}}=A \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\cong Mat_n(\mathbb{C})\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\cong Mat_n(\mathbb{C}),$$
so $$\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(A_{\mathbb{C}})=n^2.$$
What is the problem? Do I miss something?

It always holds. This is linear algebra, the algebra structure on $A$ is irrelevant. Duplicate question.

Your last isom in the computation of $A_{\mathbb{C}}$ is wrong. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648026/mathbb-c-dimension-of-vector-space-mathbb-c-otimes-mathbb-r-mathbb-c

The answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801775/tensor-product-of-a-vector-space-and-a-field answer your question.

Thank you. Hmmm, I see my mistake, I take tensoring over $\mathbb{R}$. If $A$ and $B$ are $K$-algerbas, then does $\dim_L(A_L\otimes_KB_L)=\dim_L(A_L)\dim_L(B_L)\dim_K(L)$ hold?

For the last isomorphism, do I need to write $Mat_n(\mathbb{C})\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} \cong Mat_n(\mathbb{R})\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} \cong   Mat_n(\mathbb{R})\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} (\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}) \cong Mat_n(\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C})$?

Please check out for example this text for the basics on tensor products. It's totally worth it.

But yes both of your statements are correct.
